# Probability Question with theorems?

Tags: probability

John has a biased coin with P(heads)=0.2. He tosses this coin N times and, out of the N times, the coin lands on heads 140 times. Using Markov’s inequality, he says that the probability of seeing at least this many heads is at most 0.9.

How many times did he toss the coin? N = ? (If N is a fraction, please round it up to the next integer)

Suppose John lends you this coin. If you flip the coin 437 times, what is the upper bound of the probability of seeing at least 273 heads using Markov’s inequality?
P(Number of heads>273) ≤ ***?*___**

Can someone please help me understand this problem? I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

We have a binomial process. Okay, so you have $437$ independent binomial random variables all sharing the distribution $P(X_i = 1)=.2$ and $P(X_i = 0)=.8$. $P(X_1+\cdots + X_{437}\geq 273) \leq \frac{E(X_1+\cdots + X_{437})1_{X_1+\cdots + X_{437\geq 273}}}{273} \leq \frac{EX_1+\cdots + EX_{437}}{273} = \frac{437 \cdot .2}{273} = .32$.

It's unclear about the first question because the answer is dependent on $N$. The above is my attempt at your second.